# Injecting Alphabet Dividers onto a WordPress Page

Tags: jquery, wordpress

It is not a good practice to obviously create queryloops for every letter of the alphabet and numbers on a single page which technically is a very bad solution to our problem, so we are trying to inject alphabet dividers via code on our page: https://www.newpages.com/guide-to-magazines/literary-magazines/.

It appears to be working but we've hit a snag where if the first post with a new letter starts with The, all of those posts are ignored until it comes to the first post without "the" starting the title. So The Lake is listed under K and Lake Effect is under L. I have tried googling and finding other resources, but just can't 100% find what I am looking for. Since this is a list of literary journals, we don't want to remove the from the titles if we don't have to. We do have our Post Titles set to not include "The" so they alphabetize correctly and we then have the entire name of the journals including "The" displaying in a full_name ACF extra field.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-aVKKRRi/Q/YV+4mjoKBsE4x3H+BkegoM/em46NNlCqNTmUYADjBbeNefNxYV7giUp0VxICtqdrbqU7iVaeZNXA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
  
var alpha1="";
    $(".pubgrid.gb-query-loop-wrapper>div").each(function(){
        var alpha = $(this).find("a").html().substr(0,1).toLowerCase();
        var alpha2 = $(this).find("a").html().substr(0,3).toLowerCase();
        var alpha3 = $(this).find("a").html().substr(0,4).toLowerCase();

        if(isNaN(alpha) && alpha3!="the&" && alpha3!="the " && alpha2!="the&" && alpha2!="the ")
        {
            if(alpha!=alpha1)
            {
                jQuery(this).prepend( '<div style="width:100%; display:block; clear:both; text-align:center;"><a id="'+alpha+'"></a><p><span style="font-size: 18pt;">'+alpha+'</span></p><hr class="redline"><p><a href="#top" data-uk-smooth-scroll="" target="_self">top of page</a></p></div>' );
            }
            console.log(alpha);
            alpha1 = alpha;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

There was a custom shortcode setup to load the entire list and add the anchors, but it didn't work quite like we wanted as we didn't want individual numbers showing up. We wanted numbers under one general heading, plus we didn't want to load the entire page using a shortcode vs. the default query loop.

```
$anchornew = "";
        foreach($posts as $post_single)
        {
            $anchor = ucwords(substr($post_single->post_title, 0, 1));
            
    
            if($anchor!=$anchornew)
            {
                $html .=  '<div class="anchor-link"><a href="' . $anchor . '">' . $anchor . '</a><hr>';
                $html .= '<a href="#top">top of page</a></div>';
            }
            $anchornew = $anchor;
```

Comment: Without seeing *rendered* HTML, I would hazard a guess your issue is around `$(this).find("a").html()`: 1) always `trim()` as this will include whitespace.  2) you check if it starts with "the" - then just ignore that line if it does - you should check then change your `alpha` variable to the first letter after the `the` (or `the ` or `the&nbsp;` etc)   3) use clearer variable than alpha/alpha1/alpha2  4) your comparison of substr(0,4) == "the " is the same as the comparison of substr(0,3) == "the " - substr(0,3) will be 3 characters long so will never match 4 characters.

Comment: I do have the page we are working on set to private on our site: https://www.newpages.com/guide-to-lit-mags-test/. Password is NPStack2023